# Object.values does not support in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer

I have written a javascript code for my project. That code working fine for all browser except internet explorer.

in internet explorer it says

**Object doesn't support property or method 'values'**

Here is my code

```
Object.values(products.reduce(function(c, v) {
                c[v.budget] = c[v.budget] || {id: v.budget,remainingBudget: v.remainingBudget,total: 0};
                c[v.budget].total += parseFloat(v.unitPrice)*parseFloat(v.quantity);
                return c;
              }, {})).filter(function (o) {return o.remainingBudget < o.total})
```

I did some R&D and its says that use Object.keys instead of Object.values. But i am unable to rewrite my code.

Can anybody help me to rewrite my code for internet explorer?

Comment: Use for [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill) for ie

Comment: IMO, easiest for development to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, and then use Babel and polyfills to transpile down to ugly verbose ES5. An `Object.values` polyfill shouldn't be hard to find

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try something like this    var obj = products.reduce(function(c, v) {
                    previousPayment = typeof v.previous_unit_price != 'undefined' ? v.previous_unit_price : 0;
                    c[v.budget_id] = c[v.budget_id] || {id: v.budget_id,remainingBudget: parseFloat(v.remainingBudget),total: 0, previousPayment: 0};
                    c[v.budget_id].previousPayment += parseFloat(previousPayment);
                    c[v.budget_id].total += parseFloat(v.unit_price)*parseFloat(v.quantity);
                    return c;
                  }, {})
                var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {
                    return obj[e]
                  }).filter(function (o) {return (o.remainingBudget + o.previousPayment) < o.total})
```